# Compare values inside for loop and stop if the value less than the previous value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that consists of id numbers, but this data repeats itself at a certain point. I'm trying to separate the data when it starts to repeat, so I made a for loop to do that, but it's not quite correct.

Here is the code.

```
res = []
res1 = []
for i, element in enumerate(df.id): 
    if i > 0 :
    previous_element = df.id[i-1]
           
current_element = element
    if i < len(df.id)-1:
        next_element = df.id[i+1] 
print(next_element)
    if  current_element > previous_element and current_element< next_element :
    
         res.append(current_element)
    else:
         res1.append(current_element)
```

Comment: Can you show us an example with the expected output, please?

Comment: Is the code indentation correct?

Comment: @Corralien
 res= [33]
res1=[46,46]

Comment: @ManjunathKMayya I just adjusted the indentation

Comment: @CSCS: sample input and required output would help.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution is the following:**

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

# set test data and create datafarme
data = {"id": [33, 46, 46, 50, 63, 63, 70, 71,72]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
# convert dataframe column to list
lst = df['id'].tolist()

temp = collections.Counter(lst)

results = [[i] * j for i, j in temp.items()]

print(results)
```

Prints

```
[[33], [46, 46], [50], [63, 63], [70], [71], [72]]
```

Each item in `results` can be accessed by index like:

```
results[0] # >> [33]
```

or in loop like:

```
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

Prints

```
[33]
[46, 46]
[50]
[63, 63]
[70]
[71]
[72]
```